# Flutter Image.memory() function not working with me it,s only show white images only

Tags: flutter

This is my code, it converts `base64` to `bytes`. Inside the `Container` I'm using a `MemoryImage` which is constructed from the converted `bytes`.But it is not showing up, just white space. I'm using `ImagePicker` to get the image. even with fixed `base64` string it is not working. Please help me !

my code  :

```
 Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(base64Image);

Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5)),
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: MemoryImage(bytes), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          ),
```

Comment: Where's your fixed `base64` String? I tried mine and it's working fine.

Comment: unlike base64Image in html, the base64Image in flutter should NOT contains any header, if it does, remove everthing before and including the 'comma', otherwise you'll get an invalid image, which is the white space.

Comment: problem solved for no reason. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried displaying a base64 image using [MemoryImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html) but it works fine on my end. It's possible that there might be an issue parsing the base64 image. I suggest using a checker prior to decoding the base64.

```dart
final UriData data = Uri.parse(base64ImageString).data;
if(data.isBase64) { // Check if valid base64
  Uint8List bytes = data.contentAsBytes();
  
  ...

  MemoryImage(bytes)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had an extra string in my base64 data, thank you.